# MissingInvocation of Expected static method with mocked instance parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

**I am using JMockIt 1.8**, and I have the following classes:

```
public class SimpleUser {
    public static void useSimple(final SimpleClass simple) {
        System.out.println("useSimple called");
    }

    public void createAndUse() {
        final SimpleClass simple = new SimpleClass();
        simple.method();
        SimpleUser.useSimple(simple);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SimpleClass {
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

With the following test class:

```
public class Tester {
    @Mocked SimpleClass simple;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Expectations(SimpleUser.class) {
            {
                new SimpleClass();

                simple.method();

                SimpleUser.useSimple(simple);
            }
        };

        SimpleUser user = new SimpleUser();
        user.createAndUse();
    }
}
```

And this test passes.

However, when I remove the call to `simple.method()` in `SimpleUser` and the expectation for `simple.method()` in `Tester`, the test errors with:

```
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing invocation of
  SimpleUser#useSimple(SimpleClass simple)
    with arguments: SimpleClass@45490852
```

I can cause this modified version of the test to pass by changing the expectation from `SimpleUser.useSimple(simple)` to `SimpleUser.useSimple((SimpleClass) any)`, but I would like to assert that the instance being passed through is correct.

---

Why does the behavior change depending on whether `method()` is called and **how can I ensure that `SimpleUser.useSimple()` is called with the `SimpleClass` created in `createAndUse()`, without resorting to calling a method within `SimpleClass`**.

Comment: is there a typo in your expectation - is `SimpleUser.useVisitor(simple);` correct?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo I made when reducing my code down to a MCV example

Comment: Is it really necessary to verify that a new `SimpleClass` instance was created? Seems to me like an over-specified test. I would simply verify the method was called with a non-null argument: `SimpleUser.useSimple((SimpleClass) withNotNull())`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain

> why does the behavior change depending on whether method() is called

but with JMockit 1.14 the behavior is always the same : the test fails `simple.method()` is called or not.

However, you can test what you want by adding a line in the expectation block (tested with JMockit 1.14) :

```
public class Tester {
    @Mocked
    SimpleClass simple;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Expectations(SimpleUser.class) {
            {
                new SimpleClass();
                result = simple;   // <- here

                simple.method();

                SimpleUser.useSimple(simple);
            }
        };

        SimpleUser user = new SimpleUser();
        user.createAndUse();
    }
}
```

Hope this help ...

Comment: Thanks, sadly that doesn't appear to work with JMockit 1.8, so I can't accept this answer